# Django url conflict

Tags: django

I want to set the url for a user to be example.com/user not example.com/u/user but when I try to open example.com/admin it conflict.

So I don't want to add extra pattern to the url, just the username after /. Is that possible

So

```
url(r'^u/', include('profiles.urls')),
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
```

will be

```
url(r'', include('profiles.urls')),
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
```

Comment: Aren't urls pattern-matched in order? Does it work if you put the admin/ pattern first?

Comment: url(r'^$', include('profiles.urls')),
url(r'^admin/?$', include(admin.site.urls)), I think you are missing the $ which means end of pattern. So basically everything would match. I would also put a ? sign after the last '/' which makes it optional.

Comment: @Robert How simple is that. It works :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting this as the answer since it apparently worked (see comment to question)... urls are pattern-matched in order, so if admin/ is first, it matches and you go to the admin page. Only if the pattern doesn't match 'admin/' does it match the users.

Comment: Thanks Robert for help and explanation